# If a string in lisp is a vector, why can't I access the first element using svref?

Tags: vector, lisp, common-lisp

So, I'm trying to learn Lisp, and I've come across a problem in the definition of what a String is.

I'm reading the ANSI Common Lisp by Paul Graham, and in this book it states that a String is a vector, or one-dimensional Array.

So, I create a String:

```
(defvar *my-string* "abc")
```

And then I can access the first value of *my-string* this way:

```
(aref *my-string* 0)
```

But if it is a vector, why can't I access that element this way:

```
(svref *my-string* 0)
```

I mean, when I create a vector this way:

```
(defvar my-vec (make-array 4 :initial-element 1))
```

I can access first element using svref:

```
(svref my-vec 0) ; returns 1
```

I forgot to add error when I try svref on String:

"The value "abc" is not of type (SIMPLE-ARRAY T (*))."

Comment: What is the error message or behavior you're actually getting from svref?

Comment: @RobertHarvey thanks for reminding me! The reason why I'm asking is because I constantly work with Strings, and I read in Graham's book that svref is faster than aref, so wanted to see if I could utilise this in my coding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

String is a vector, but it isn't a simple-vector. [svref](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_svref.htm) takes a simple-vector as first argument.

You can check it by calling:

```
(vector-p *my-string*)
```

which returns true

Unlike:

```
(simple-vector-p *my-string*)
```

which returns false.

Notice that `(simple-vector-p my-vec)` will return true as well, which confirms that `make-array` creates a simple-vector.

Comment: So, could you explain what the difference between a vector and simple-vector is, I can't find it in the documentation? I can only find that simple-vector is a subtype of vector.

Comment: @ArashSaidi [here's a nice discussion of the subject](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/collections.html). Basically simple-vectors are specialized to hold certain type of elements. strings are another specialization of vectors, but they're not simple-vectors.

Comment: Thanks, will look into it. Was planning on reading that book after Graham's!

Comment: @ArashSaidi It may just be a typo, but I think that description is backwards:  a simple-vector is one that can hold *any* time of element.  The documentation for simple-vector says that its element type is **t**;  that is, it can hold *any* type of element.  If you consider the possible implementations, this becomes a bit clearer:  if a vector is specialized for a particular type (e.g., cons), then the vector could hold the cons cells "in place", but if a vector is a simple vector, then it's essentially an array of (what would be in C) void pointers.  It would make the pointer arithmetic...

Comment: ... much simpler, and (I'd expect) that svref can take advantage of that fact.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor yeah I mixed that up.

Answer (score 5):

[soulcheck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26164599/1281433) is absolutely right, but it's worth the time to become comfortable with the HyperSpec. For instance, if you start at the page for [svref](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_svref.htm), there's a note at the bottom:

> #### Notes:
>
> **svref** is identical to [**aref**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_aref.htm#aref) except that it requires its first argument to be a [*simple vector*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_s.htm#simple_vector).

The glossary entry for *simple vector* (linked above) says:

> **simple vector** *n.* a *vector* of *type* **simple-vector**, sometimes called a "*simple general vector*." Not all *vectors* that are *simple* are *simple vectors*—only those that have *element type* **t**.

[15.2 The Arrays Dictionary](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/c_arrays.htm) is also helpful here, as is [15. Arrays](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/15_.htm) as  a whole.